# Tensorboard shows nothing in chrome

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm new to use the tensorflow. when I start to use the tensorboard,I run the demo code `mnist_with_summaries.py`, it runs with no error.but when I input `tensorboard --logdir=/tmp/mnist/logs` and open the chrome it shows nothing. So I follow the guide to find the error.
I input

```
find /tmp/mnist/logs | grep tfevents
```

it shows

```
/tmp/mnist/logs/test/events.out.tfevents.1487988017.wangxiaoyu
/tmp/mnist/logs/train/events.out.tfevents.1487988016.wangxiaoyu
```

I input

```
tensorboard --inspect --logdir=/tmp/mnist/logs
```

it shows

```
======================================================================
Processing event files... (this can take a few minutes)
======================================================================

Found event files in:
/tmp/mnist/logs/test
/tmp/mnist/logs/train

These tags are in /tmp/mnist/logs/test:
audio -
histograms
   layer1/Wx_plus_b/pre_activations
   layer1/activations
   layer1/biases/summaries/histogram
   layer1/weights/summaries/histogram
   layer2/Wx_plus_b/pre_activations
   layer2/activations
   layer2/biases/summaries/histogram
   layer2/weights/summaries/histogram
images
   input_reshape/input/image/0
   input_reshape/input/image/1
   input_reshape/input/image/2
   input_reshape/input/image/3
   input_reshape/input/image/4
   input_reshape/input/image/5
   input_reshape/input/image/6
   input_reshape/input/image/7
   input_reshape/input/image/8
   input_reshape/input/image/9
scalars
   accuracy_1
   cross_entropy_1
   dropout/dropout_keep_probability
   layer1/biases/summaries/max
   layer1/biases/summaries/mean
   layer1/biases/summaries/min
   layer1/biases/summaries/stddev_1
   layer1/weights/summaries/max
   layer1/weights/summaries/mean
   layer1/weights/summaries/min
   layer1/weights/summaries/stddev_1
   layer2/biases/summaries/max
   layer2/biases/summaries/mean
   layer2/biases/summaries/min
   layer2/biases/summaries/stddev_1
   layer2/weights/summaries/max
   layer2/weights/summaries/mean
   layer2/weights/summaries/min
   layer2/weights/summaries/stddev_1
======================================================================

Event statistics for /tmp/mnist/logs/test:
audio -
graph -
histograms
   first_step           0
   last_step            990
   max_step             990
   min_step             0
   num_steps            100
   outoforder_steps     []
images
   first_step           0
   last_step            990
   max_step             990
   min_step             0
   num_steps            100
   outoforder_steps     []
scalars
   first_step           0
   last_step            990
   max_step             990
   min_step             0
   num_steps            100
   outoforder_steps     []
sessionlog:checkpoint -
sessionlog:start -
sessionlog:stop -
======================================================================

These tags are in /tmp/mnist/logs/train:
audio -
histograms
   layer1/Wx_plus_b/pre_activations
   layer1/activations
   layer1/biases/summaries/histogram
   layer1/weights/summaries/histogram
   layer2/Wx_plus_b/pre_activations
   layer2/activations
   layer2/biases/summaries/histogram
   layer2/weights/summaries/histogram
images
   input_reshape/input/image/0
   input_reshape/input/image/1
   input_reshape/input/image/2
   input_reshape/input/image/3
   input_reshape/input/image/4
   input_reshape/input/image/5
   input_reshape/input/image/6
   input_reshape/input/image/7
   input_reshape/input/image/8
   input_reshape/input/image/9
scalars
   accuracy_1
   cross_entropy_1
   dropout/dropout_keep_probability
   layer1/biases/summaries/max
   layer1/biases/summaries/mean
   layer1/biases/summaries/min
   layer1/biases/summaries/stddev_1
   layer1/weights/summaries/max
   layer1/weights/summaries/mean
   layer1/weights/summaries/min
   layer1/weights/summaries/stddev_1
   layer2/biases/summaries/max
   layer2/biases/summaries/mean
   layer2/biases/summaries/min
   layer2/biases/summaries/stddev_1
   layer2/weights/summaries/max
   layer2/weights/summaries/mean
   layer2/weights/summaries/min
   layer2/weights/summaries/stddev_1
======================================================================

Event statistics for /tmp/mnist/logs/train:
audio -
graph
   first_step           0
   last_step            0
   max_step             0
   min_step             0
   num_steps            1
   outoforder_steps     []
histograms
   first_step           1
   last_step            999
   max_step             999
   min_step             1
   num_steps            900
   outoforder_steps     []
images
   first_step           1
   last_step            999
   max_step             999
   min_step             1
   num_steps            900
   outoforder_steps     []
scalars
   first_step           1
   last_step            999
   max_step             999
   min_step             1
   num_steps            900
   outoforder_steps     []
sessionlog:checkpoint -
sessionlog:start -
sessionlog:stop -
```

but when I input

```
tensorboard --logdir=/tmp/mnist/logs
```

it shows

```
Starting TensorBoard 46 on port 6006
(You can navigate to http://127.0.1.1:6006)
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:6006/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2017 10:20:17] "GET /polymer/polymer-mini.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2017 10:20:17] "GET /iron-icon/iron-icon.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2017 10:20:17] "GET /iron-iconset-svg/iron-iconset-svg.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2017 10:20:17] "GET /iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2017 10:20:17] "GET /iron-resizable-behavior/iron-resizable-behavior.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2017 10:20:17] "GET /paper-styles/color.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2017 10:20:17] "GET /iron-menu-behavior/iron-menubar-behavior.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2017 10:20:17] "GET /paper-tabs/paper-tabs-icons.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2017 10:20:17] "GET /paper-tabs/paper-tab.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2017 10:20:17] "GET /neon-animation/neon-animation-runner-behavior.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2017 10:20:17] "GET /paper-dialog-behavior/paper-dialog-behavior.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2017 10:20:17] "GET /paper-dialog-behavior/paper-dialog-shared-styles.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
*** Error in `/home/wangxiaoyu/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/bin/python': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x000000000085efa0 ***
已放弃 (核心已转储)
```

So I can't watch anything in the chrome.

Could anyone help me?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Does it work with another browser ?

Comment: does not look like a browser issue